# Filtering with nested arrays

Tags: javascript, filter, knockout.js

I will give an example below that I am writing using knockout, but the logic works using standard js.

```
<!-- ko foreach: { data: ourWorks, as: 'item' } -->
    <div data-bind="visible: $parent.isVisible(item) "></div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Js logic that works if there is only one value in tags.name

```
isVisible: function (item) {
    let itemTag = item.tags || [];
    return !!this.chosenTags().length && this.chosenTags().length > 0 ? this.chosenTags().includes(itemTag.name) : item;
},
```

But if there are several values, everything stops working. I tried to implement the logic for nested arrays, but it doesn't work, tell me how to implement it?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEYko.png)

```
isVisible: function (item) {
    let itemTag = item.tags || [];
    if (Array.isArray(itemTag)) {
        let tags = this.chosenTags();
        return itemTag.reduce(function(accum, currentVal, currentIndex, tags) {
            return tags ? tags.includes(currentVal) : false;
        }, this);
    }
    return !!this.chosenTags().length && this.chosenTags().length > 0 ? this.chosenTags().includes(itemTag.name) : item;
},
```

Comment: How is it not working? Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `some` if you want the item to be visible if *one or more* of its tag names appear in `chosenTags`. If *all* of them should be in `chosenTags`, you use `every`:

```js
isVisible: function(item) {
  const itemTags = item.tags || [];
  const chosen = this.chosenTags() || [];

  return itemTags.some(t => chosen.includes(t));
}
```